# While Restoring the Sql Server Data base Status is Stuck

Tags: sql-server, database, database-restore

I am facing one problem ie.
I create one data base...
and then I restored it...
the back up is from the existing data base only..
after successfully restored old one ie. parent one is showing that

```
"BRPL_Payroll _31-01-2014" (Restoring.........)
```

like above it is showing....

and then i execute the below query..

```
RESTORE DATABASE BRPL_Payroll _31-01-2014 ;WITH RECOVERY
```

but here it is showing that incorrect syntax at '-'

I think my data base name is having some date  31-01-2014
how can i execute the above query...

Comment: hey srinivas, please let us know what kind of Database Server you use. I edited tag SQL-Server since I think you use MS SQL-Server.

Comment: Your database name is not a "regular identifier".  That means it needs to be delimited.  Also, the semicolon is in the wrong place. Try this:  `RESTORE DATABASE [BRPL_Payroll _31-01-2014] WITH RECOVERY;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily restore a database Using the  UI and before pressing `OK` to restore you select `Script` and SQL-Server will show you the script (Query) you need to run in order to execute the step.

[image: Database restore]

If you don't have direct access I can give you a restore script which works to restore a database from file. But you have to replace of course the path to your DB and your DB Name :

```
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE [YURDATABASENAME] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [YURDATABASENAME] FROM  DISK = N'C:\your\backup\path\backup.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
ALTER DATABASE [YURDATABASENAME] SET MULTI_USER

GO
```